# How to set JSON payload on AmazoneWebServiceRequest

Tags: java, android, aws-sdk

I am using AmazonHttpClient & AmazonWebServiceRequest to make http requests to API gateway from android app. The `requestBody` is a JSON String and DefaultRequest only seem to accept `InputStream` as content.

```
final AmazonWebServiceRequest awsRequest = new AmazonWebServiceRequest() {};
final Request request = new DefaultRequest(awsRequest, UtilConstants.API_GATEWAY_SERVICE_NAME);
request.setEndpoint(uri);
request.setHttpMethod(requestType);
request.addHeader(HttpHeader.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
final InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(requestBody.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
request.setContent(stream);
```

When I make the request I get following exception

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: expected 0 bytes but received 38
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding `HttpHeader.CONTENT_LENGTH` header solved the issue.

Comment: Hi,  I am having similar issue, without ContentLength, I am not receiving json on the other end, when added ContentLength I am getting 
"errorMessage": "Unable to execute HTTP request: Request did not complete before the request timeout configuration.", error. while sending request. Any suggestion on this?